# Warning: Illegal string offset in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, string, warnings

I upgraded to PHP 5.4 today and I am receiving some strange warnings:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'quote1' in file.php on line 110
Warning: Illegal string offset 'quote1_title' in file.php on line 111
```

Those lines are this part of the code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $tmp_url = $meta['quote'. ($i+1)];
    $tmp_title = $meta['quote' . ($i+1) .'_title'];

    if(!empty($tmp_url) || !empty($tmp_title)) {
        $quotes[$src_cnt] = array();
        $quotes[$src_cnt]['url'] = $tmp_url;
        $quotes[$src_cnt]['title'] = $tmp_title;
        $src_cnt++;
    }
}
```

So the `$tmp_url` and `$tmp_title` line.

Why am I receiving this odd warning and what is the solution?

**Update**:

This code is being used as a Wordpress plugin. $meta includes:

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_quote_source',TRUE);
```

So I am suspecting that whenever the quotes fields are empty, this warning appears. Is there any way that I can fix this for when the fields are empty?

Comment: `quote1_title` and `quote1` doesn't exist in your $meta array.
Can you show us your $meta contents.

Comment: What does `var_dump($meta)` show? It's probably not an array.

Comment: This is a plugin for a Wordpress site: `$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_quote_source',TRUE);`

Comment: The message is clear (`$meta` is a string, not an array) and Marc's tip (`var_dump()`) is the way to know for sure. The fact that code belongs to an undisclosed Wordpress plug-in doesn't change this because Wordpress plugins are PHP code as well.

Comment: When executing `var_dump($meta)` on a page where there were nothing written in the quote fields, it shows `NULL`. This is when I receive the warning. However, on pages where the quote fields have been filled it, it works fine. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure, that `$meta` is actually of type array. The warning explicitly tells you, that `$meta` seems to be a `string` and not an `array`

```
Illegal string offset
        ^^^^^^
```

To avoid this error you may also check for the needed fields

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    if ( !is_array($meta) || !array_key_exists('quote'. ($i+1), $meta) ){
         continue;
    }
    // your code
}
```

Comment: When executing `var_dump($meta)` on a page where there were nothing written in the quote fields, it shows `NULL`. This is when I receive the warning. However, on pages where the quote fields have been filled it, it works fine. How do I solve this?

Comment: check for null before: `isset($meta['quote'. ($i+1)])` oder `array_key_exists('quote'. ($i+1), $meta)`

Comment: Can you please update your answer with this suggestion.

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Works great! Thank you, I have one final request before I accept this as correct. Can you please explain what this new IF statement does in detail? I just want to understand the solution.

Comment: Also, it appears that other people using this plugin are experiencing the same errors, if you see this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-quote-source-debug-shows-error  it is suggested to add `if(!empty)` call before running the for-loop. That is what we did here, correct?

Comment: it is actually doing two things. 1. check if `$meta` is an array (`is_array`) or 2. that the key exists with `array_key_exists` in the array `$meta`.

Comment: So this solution will make that part of the script stop running on pages where the meta is empty, correct?

Comment: it will not stop, just skip that part of the code and I would use `isset` instead of `empty` which is more used for strings

Comment: So in this case, is the solution posted at that thread any different to the one that we have here? I am asking this because I will be posting this solution there for others to use (I will credit you of course).

Comment: yes that should solve the problem stated in the thread

Answer (score 0):

If `$meta` is `null` whenever there's no data to process:

```
if( !is_null($meta) ){
    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You should be able to do more checks if necessary. That depends on what that `get_post_meta()` function is designed to return.

Comment: It appears that other people are having the same problem with this plugin: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-quote-source-debug-shows-error In that thread, it is suggested to add `if(!empty)` call before running the for-loop. Can you kindly update your answer with this fix and I will accept it as correct.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, Stack Overflow actually encourages it. But if `$meta` is null my answer should be just fine.

Comment: It is strange, MatthiasLaug's solution works. Thank you regardless for the effort.

Comment: It isn't strange. They're endless ways to fix one same problem. That's what I mean with doing more checks: you'll need to do more or less checks depending on what `get_post_meta()` can return. Just try to understand each answer you've got and use the one that makes more sense to you.