# PHP isset returns true but should be false

Tags: php, cakephp, isset, cakephp-2.4

My project is in cakePHP but I think this is an aspect of native PHP that I am misunderstanding..

I have an `afterFind($results, $primary = false)` callback method in my `AppModel`. On one particular find if I `debug($results);` I get an array like this

```
array(
    'id' => '2',
    'price' => '79.00',
    'setup_time' => '5',
    'cleanup_time' => '10',
    'duration' => '60',
    'capacity' => '1',
    'discontinued' => false,
    'service_category_id' => '11'
)
```

In my `afterFind` I have some code like this:

```
foreach($results as &$model) {
  // if multiple models
  if(isset($model[$this->name][0])) {
    ....
```

The results of the find are from my `Service` model so inserting that for `$this->name` and checking `if(isset($model['Service'][0]))` should return false but it returns true? `if(isset($model['Service']))` returns false as expected.

I am getting the following PHP warning:

> Illegal string offset 'Service'

so what's going on here? why does `if(isset($model['Service'][0]))` return true if `if(isset($model['Service']))` returns false?

**UPDATE:**

I still don't know the answer to my original question but I got around it by first checking if $results is a multidimensional array with

`if(count($results) != count($results, COUNT_RECURSIVE))`

Comment: Look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16264301/577470

Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869150/illegal-string-offset-warning-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_key_exists()` or `empty()` instead of `isset()`. PHP caches old array values strangely. They have to be manually unset using `unset()`

isset() does not return TRUE for array keys that correspond to a NULL value, while [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) does.

Answer (score 0):

String offsets provide a mechanism to use strings as if they were an array of characters:

```
$string = 'abcde';
echo $string[2]; // c
```

`$model` is indeed a string for all keys except *discontinued*.

As for the `isset($model['Service'][0])` return value, I'm a bit surprised. This is a simplified test case:

```
$model = '2';
var_dump(isset($model['Service'])); // bool(false)
var_dump(isset($model['Service'][0])); // bool(true)
```

There must be a reason somewhere. Will have a dig..

Comment: What's happening here is that 'Service' is invalid as a string index. If you have warnings turned on, you'll get "PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'Service'... However, aside from the warning PHP will happily try do do something. So it converts the invalid index to 0. $model['Service'] returns '2'. Therefore $model['Service'][0] is also '2'. See the link roliveira provides above for details.